# Neo4j not functional through apache proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, neo4j

I am able to run neo4j fine through port 7474 on my server including cypher queries. Though when I access neo4j through the apache proxy it will load just fine but any requests done through cypher will only return an "Unknown error". I have other proxies such as rstudio running just fine.

I have tried the default values on the neo4j website for proxy configuration with no success. I am at a loss for what to try. Please let me know for more information needed, or how I can get additional information on the cypher error.

I tried the sample Query:

```
CREATE (n {name:"World"}) RETURN "hello", n.name
```

And this returns "Unknown error" when done through the proxy, but when done through port 7474 it works fine

This is a Linux Ubuntu LTR 12.04.4 machine. 
Neo4j 2.1.1
Apache 2.2.22
Sorry if this is vague but I have not found any help for this issue nor do I know what additional information would be relevant.

Thank you.

Update:

It now works with the case provided by Stefan (Thank you!). But I am unsure how to change it from being on the root of my domain to "/database/" in your example you can change it to "/neo4j" How would I change the other parts of this config file for this to function?

As it looks now (non functional with change of proxy from "/"):

```
 ProxyPass /database/ http://localhost:7474/
 ProxyPassReverse /database/ http://localhost:7474/
 RedirectMatch permanent ^/database /database/
    <Location /db/manage>
            AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
            Substitute "s|http://localhost:7474|http://localhost:8080|n"
    </Location>
```

I tried to change the substitute rule from "localhost:8080" to "localhost:8080/database" and to "/database" to no avail.

In closing what worked is to make it a subdomain and still have it on the root. Not sure why this has to be the case, but it is functional. Thank you again Stefan!

Comment: give us your test query and how you're calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've setup a example config for using `mod_proxy` and `mod_substitute`, see https://github.com/sarmbruster/vagrant_neo4j_modproxy.  See esp the [Apache config file](https://github.com/sarmbruster/vagrant_neo4j_modproxy/blob/master/etc/apache2/sites-available/default).
Be aware that mod_substitute will not work with huge responses > 1M.

Comment: Thank you! This works great, as of now I am just unsure how to change it from being on the root domain (See update of my question). Appreciate it Stefan.

Comment: not sure, but I guess you have to change `http://localhost:8080` in the substitute rule to `http://<yourdomain>/database`

Comment: Hm, no this did not work. for your additional URL paths that are commented out:
    #ProxyPass /neo4j/ http://localhost:7474/
    #ProxyPassReverse /neo4j/ http://localhost:7474/, 
how do you get this to function? This is essentially what I want

Comment: I didn't get it to work with non root URL. As a workaround consider usage of named virtualhosts, e.g. app.mydomain.com and neo4j.mydomain.com.

Comment: OK, I'm going to try this and let you know how it goes. Thank you